# Events queue in a different machine than the agent one

Tags: flume

For HA purposes, I need the files supporting a JDBC/File Channel are stored in a machine different than the agent one (this is because a secondary agent running in a third machine will be sharing the channel). Is it possible? Can you give me a configuration example?

Comment: Channels cannot be shared between agents. At least, not concurrently. Could you add a more detailed explanation about what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Due to certain high availability requirements, 2 different machines will be running the same Flume agent code in an active/passive configuration. When the active agent crashes for some reason, the passive one must wake up and start processing new incoming events, but it must process the buffered events within the first agent's channel as well. As you can see, there is no concurrent access at any moment. Ideally, the files supporting the channel should be living in a 3rd machine.